# Loading external jquery scripts based on browser size

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, external

I have three different css files I use depending on how big the users screen is, that way it looks good on mobile devices and such.  Ex:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 568px)" href="css/small.css" />
```

Currently I am using some jquery that deals with the page width as well, and to keep things simpler I'd love to load external jquery scripts in the same way the css is done.  Is this a possibility?

Comment: What if the user resizes the browser after the page loads?

Comment: _"to keep things simpler"_ - Maintaining and conditionally loading separate scripts sounds less simple to me. Don't you end up with duplicated code if you do that?

Comment: the code im using right now accommodates for that.  I set 3/4 different external files to be triggered based on size, so however big it is it will work.  It can update even after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Using `JavaScript` you can determine the size of `screen`

```
screen.height;
screen.width;
```

For example, you can use

```
if(window.screen.width <= 580) {
    //...
}
```

Using [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) (also possible without `jQuery`) you can load a script

```
$.getScript( "yourscript.js");
```

But, I think, you want something like `css media query` to determine the device, whether it's a handheld device or not and if so, then you may try [this plugin](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/).

Comment: this should work, but it's not accepting multiple scripts.  Like" if its this size open this one, if its smaller: open this one" it always chooses the first script and loads that.